# Android NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, layout, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater

I have following two Fragment containing TextView and Button:

```
public class MyFragmentText extends Fragment {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

public static final MyFragmentText newInstance(String message)
{
    MyFragmentText f = new MyFragmentText();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
    bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    f.setArguments(bdl);
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_text, container, false);
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    messageTextView.setText(message);
    return v;
}
```

}

and

```
public class MyFragmentButton extends Fragment {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

    public static final MyFragmentButton newInstance(String message)
    {
        MyFragmentButton f = new MyFragmentButton();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_button, container, false);
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        messageTextView.setText(message);

        return v;
    }
}
```

and I have three XML files that are:

Main layout:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Button layout

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click here"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Textview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when I am calling them from Main program to show sliding windows with the following code, it works nicely.

public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

```
MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);

    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    //btn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    //btn.setText("Hello World!!!");
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    fList.add(MyFragmentButton.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
    fList.add(MyFragmentText.newInstance("Fragment 2"));

    return fList;
}

private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

}

but if I apply

```
btn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setText("Hello World!!!");
```

it gives me Null pointer exception. I guess it's due the the fact that thet lauyout is not inflated when I am calling the btn. I would appreciate if anyone could suggest any solution.

Comment: Can you show exactly activity_page_view xml layout please?

Comment: Mightyseal, I just updated my post to show three layout files

Answer (score 0):

As far as i undesrtand `activity_page_view xml` is this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout has no elemnt with button, that's why `btn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);` returns `null` and `btn.setText("Hello World!!!");` produces NPE

Comment: Is there any way to access controls from other layout? I mean inflate the other layouts and acces the controls

Comment: @MKS there is, you can create method in fragment which will return control you want, but the idea sounds not good. Basically it's better when the component (activity or fragment) encapsulates it's controls. If you want to change controls state from another component you should somehow send event which component catches and updates controls. You can use broadcast, or event bus like otto. If you need the simpliest solution — just create you own interface for that purpose.